# How to use dropbox img link in csv for product import magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to use Dropbox img link in csv for product import magento 1.9.

Comment: how you import products ?

Comment: using csv import from admin panel.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/some_linkanrn5nrf/door%20visors.jpg      i want to use  this type of link in my csv product import file .

Comment: try to use http://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/products.html for import refer https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport/issues/108

Comment: @Gopal Patel It's doesn't work for me . I want to use external link for product image. Can we override core functionality in abstract class

Comment: External link will work but dropbox needs authentication thats why image is not accessible via direct link

Comment: Is there any way to do this . As if i hit the Dropbox URL manually in browser images are shown.  Thank you so much for replying.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who is facing this kind of issue to import product images from dropbox, here is the fix.

**In the "URL" field, simply paste the link (ending in ?dl=1) you determined above**

Comment: Is this valid for Magento 2.x as well ?

Comment: Yes, it works for any platform